# SQL Server Select line where jobCategoryKey EXISTS once for one candidateKey

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'm blocked with an SQL Query that I have to made on SQL Server 2014.

Here is my table `TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category`.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category]
       ( [candidateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
         [jobCategoryKey] [int] NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
            ( [candidateKey] ASC, [jobCategoryKey] ASC )
            WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
       ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (2, 223)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (2, 1245)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (2, 225)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (5, 137)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (5, 142)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (5, 143)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (6, 1245)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (6, 223)
INSERT [dbo].[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category] ([candidateKey], [jobCategoryKey]) VALUES (6, 225)
```

I have to find all the candidates which have the `jobCategoryKey` = 1245 and only this one. So they may not have one or more other `jobCategoryKey` or zero `jobCategoryKey`.

I tried with `HAVING`, `GROUP BY` and so on, but I didn't find the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

All the proposed solutions using COUNT may prove to be inefficient as the aggregates will most likely need to be computed for the entire set, unless the optimizer will be able to push the predicate down. There is a more natural solution which IMHO is much clearer, and typically more efficient. It involves wording the question in negative form:

> "Show me all candidates for category 1245, who have no other
>   association with any other category".

This translates to SQL immediately:

```
SELECT *
FROM Candidates_to_Jobs AS C1
WHERE jobCategoryKey = 1245
      AND 
      NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT NULL
                  FROM Candidates_to_Jobs AS C2
                  WHERE C1.CandidateKey = C2.CandidateKey
                        AND C2.jobCategoryKey <> 1245
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

```
-- query 1
SELECT [candidateKey]
FROM dbo.[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category]
GROUP BY [candidateKey]
HAVING MIN( [jobCategoryKey] ) = 1245
   AND MAX( [jobCategoryKey] ) = 1245 ;
```

An index on `(candidateKey, jobCategoryKey)` would help with the above query.

```
-- query 2
SELECT [candidateKey]
FROM dbo.[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category]
WHERE [jobCategoryKey] = 1245
EXCEPT 
SELECT [candidateKey]
FROM dbo.[TR_Candidate_To_Jobs_Category]
WHERE [jobCategoryKey] <> 1245 ;
```

---

SQLRaptor's query might be more efficient - especially if there are few candidate keys with `jobCategoryKey = 1245`. It might need the index with the order reversed though (or both of them).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
WITH getSingle AS
(
    SELECT candidateKey,
            COUNT(1)
    FROM Candidate_To_Jobs_Category
    GROUP BY candidateKey
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
)
SELECT C.candidateKey,
FROM Candidate_To_Jobs_Category C
    INNER JOIN getSingle gs ON C.candidateKey = gs.candidateKey
WHERE c.jobCategoryKey = 1245
```

This code first gets the candidates with only one record in the table. In the second step, only the candidates with key 1245 are selected, based on the fact that there's only one record in the table for that specific candidate.